# Bold markdown does not seem to function inside code sections

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, formatting

As can be seen in the edit history of [Set Request Timeout in Elastic Search for bulk loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326837/set-request-timeout-in-elastic-search-for-bulk-loads/42672737#42672737), an editor tried to emphasize a section of code by making it bold. But apparently this does not function as desired.

i.e.

```
`bulk(es, records, chunk_size=500, **request_timeout=20**)`
```

leads to:

`bulk(es, records, chunk_size=500, **request_timeout=20**)`

Is this a bug, or expected behaviour?

Comment: Markdown doesn't work in code blocks (This is by-design)

Comment: Don't add formatting in code...

Comment: Yes?! And what will you do when you need a pointer to pointer?

Comment: @AlonEitan refactor? :p

Answer (score 6):

It seems reasonable to represent code literally (particularly if the code itself is Markdown code).  It's quite reasonable, in some languages, for code to contain character sequences that look like Markdown - for example `__init__` and other similar magic method names in Python - and we don't want the site mangling our code.

Therefore, I'd argue that what you see is desirable, and likely intended.

If there's a bug, it's that the editor (toolbar and control-key combinations) will attempt to apply such formatting to text that's already in a code markdown.